# How to quickly step into require() call while debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging Node.js code with `--inspect-brk` and Chrome Devtools, I can step into a function call pretty easily by pressing [image: the "step into" button] (F11). However, when it comes to `require()` calls, e.g.

```
var cmd = require(path.join(__dirname, a + '.js'))
```

it will first step into `path.join()` (which is reasonable), but then into `internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77`, not actually the start of `./a.js` file. I do not care about how Node.js handles require calls, only the code inside the required module.

So the question is, while using step into on require calls, how can I quickly skip the internal code and go straight to the file "required"?

Comment: You can probably [blackbox](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing) helpers.js in devtools so it'll be skipped on stepping-in.

Answer (score 0):

One method I found, is that I can open the required module directly in Devtools and set a breakpoint:

1. add it to the workspace via `Sources` => `Filesystem` => `+`
2. open it in sources tab
3. set a breakpoint at line 1
4. resume script execution (F8). It will run until reaching the breakpoint.

However, it requires the path containing the required module to be added to the workspace, which can be slow depending on the size of the folder. Also, files inside `node_modules` are ignored by default.